# Save a copy of a file in a specific folder on opening the file

Tags: excel, vba, copy, save

I have an Excel workbook that is used by a lot of people and can easily be ruined.

How can I by opening the Excel workbook (file) automatically save a copy to a specific folder?

The Excel workbook is in SharePoint so I can create a new folder in the same location with the name 'Archive' and by opening the file a new copy of that file with the same name + "DD.MM.YYY HH:MM:SS" will be saved here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about sharepoint, but this work if the file is saved in a regular folder. Solution could be made in different ways.

Save the code in the following place in the VBA Editor. Name the sub to "`Private Sub Workbook_Open()`" - to indicate that excel should execute the code when it opens up. 
You can see that you have succeed when the "procedure" field changes to "Open", marked yellow in the picture.
[image]

**Alternative 1:**

Here I hardcode my path by writing `"G:\Till\"`. Then I proceed with adding the timestamp and choose which format. Notice for time you can't use the *semicolon* ":" in the path. One way is to add "T" for Time and then the hour+minute+second.
In my example code the result will be: "Data Example - 2019-11-03 T203533.xlsm"

Notice that this code will get a Error 1004, if the path doesn't exist.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Fldr As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Hide any save window pop-up
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="G:\Till\" & "Data Example - " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd Thhmmss") & ".xlsm" 'Save the workbook as a copy of the original. Add Hour and timestamp
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**Alternative 2:**

To make the code more robust I check the pathway of the workbook I use and then check if the folder "Archive" exists. If it doesn't exist it will create the folder and save a copy of the file.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Fldr As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Hide any save window pop-up
Fldr = Dir(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Archive\", vbDirectory) 'Check if folder exists. The variable will be empty if no folder exists.

If Fldr = Empty Then 'If no folder exist, the variable "Folder"
    MkDir Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Archive\" 'Create the folder
End If

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Archive\" & "Data Example - " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd Thhmmss") & ".xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```